# vb.net Postgressql - .net app runs fine on devl vm but when running on a client machine have DLL error

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I have a vb.net app which runs fine on the developer machine but when running it from the client machine with PGSQL (v12) installed, I get this dll error when performing a connection to the local machine server from the app itself.

postgresql Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The DLL is references in the vb.net executable and I can confirm the DLL has been copied to the client app directory - I did not "install" it there as such, but a literal file copy as I have my app set up so it will run off-the-cuff, the only installations I have had to do, was with the VS C++ libraries and RDLC report setup. I'd rather not do an uninstall of the app from the client but am happy to install a different app if it gets that running

I cannot find anything on the internet that is indicating what is wrong other than the above.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using [npgsql](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql) then it appears you need to install it on the target machine using the provided MSI file, as the library has other dependencies that need to be present. If you still get the same error, you might want to follow [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2677), which is currently being investigated. According to two different users, downgrading to 4.0.10 or 4.0.9 solved their issue (assuming you're using the latest version).

Comment: Ah brilliant. I'll hang on, see if the dev fixes the issue, meanwhile Im trying my app with mysql as its going to be multi-db compliant so I have plenty to be getting on with, thanks! :)